# Windows 7 64-bit System Repair Loop

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

My system is stuck on System Repair Loop. The Windows System Repair fails to repair with error "Missing OSLoader"

I tried to fix with a solution suggested in a Windows forum: *[Automated Startup Repair fails. Cannot find OS Loader](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/automated-startup-repair-fails-cannot-find-os/81789756-858e-4adc-a25b-2c0d0c234e0d)*, but the command

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

returns

```
Total identified windows installations:0
```

Any ideas how to fix the bootloader?

Answer (score 3):

August 2019 Windows 7 update caused this problem.  This solution worked for me so I thought I would share:

1. Boot from a Clean Win 7 ISO.
2. Goto repair this PC and then go to the Command Prompt.
3. Type this to revert the changes:

   ```
   dism.exe /image:c:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
   ```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I wish you see this, I am adding this to my horror stories that almost ended very badly :)

Comment: For people who had this problem specifically because August 2019 update: try to shut down your pc completely and wait a little. Not just restart, but completely turn off, wait, then turn on again. That fixed it for me, it should be some bios problem i think.

Comment: I ran this through the Command line option from the recovery options after the error and it fixed the problem for me, there was no need to boot from a clean ISO. Now Windows says these updates failed: KB4474419, KB4535102 and KB4516065. One of those is a Monthly Quality Rollup from September 2019, so I'm guessing it contains the update that causes this. Anyway, thank you very much for this info, it was of great help!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: Perform `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` `bootrec.exe /fixboot` and `bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd` in that order from a windows 7 DVD or USB. Is a guide to help you make a USB windows 7 iso. http://www.techverse.net/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-pen-drive-for-windows-7/

Comment: hey , unfortunately i already tried this with the last command to be bootrec /rebuildbcd but its not fixing the bootloader and i get "Total identified windows installations:0" on bootrec /rebuildbcd

Comment: You did this from a dvd or usb with windows on it and not the recovery partition?

Comment: I did this from the Windows 7 DVD with the Windows HDD on.

I originally have dual boot with Linux on another HDD (primary boot-loader was Windows) but i removed the other HDD After the recovery loop issue. So right now the PC only contains the windows HDD

Comment: Is your HDD connected via USB? If so can you confirm that it is not being connected to a SS port (USB 3.0)?

Comment: HDD is connected on SATA port. Its my primary OS Hard Disk Drive. I can browse and see all data of the disk fine using a Linux Live CD

Answer (score 0):

I found these instructions on the [Microsoft forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/total-identified-windows-installations-0/52359f87-de4a-41dc-b0c3-cc275e1d9fbf), which were posted by ***Vijay B***. I've formatted them in a way that makes more sense to me. *Since you've already partially completed these steps, you'll want to start at step 5.*

1. First Start System Recovery Options. To start system recovery options.
   a) Boot from the disk, Once you get the welcome screen of installation with the option “Install now”

   - Click on Repair your computer
   - On the next page click on Advanced Options
   - Now click on Troubleshoot
   - Lastly click on Command prompt and follow the on screen instructions
2. At the prompt, type the bootrec command as shown below and then press Enter:

   ```
   bootrec /rebuildbcd
   ```

The bootrec command will search for Windows installations not included in the Boot Configuration Data and then ask you if you'd like to add one or more to it.

3. If you see the following message, proceed to step 10.

   ```
   Scanning all disks for Windows installations.
   Please wait, since this may take a while...
   Successfully scanned Windows installations.
   Total identified Windows installations: 1
   [1]  D:\Windows
   Add installation to boot list? Yes<Y>/No<N>/All<A>:
   ```
4. If you see the following message, proceed.

   ```
   Scanning all disks for Windows installations.  
   Please wait, since thismay take a while...  
   Successfully scanned Windows installations.  
   Total identified Windows installations: 0  
   The operation completed successfully.
   ```
5. Since the BCD store exists but does not list a Windows installation, you'll first have to remove it manually and then try to rebuild it again.

At the prompt, execute the bcdedit command as shown and then press Enter:

```
    bcdedit /export c:\bcdbackup
```

The bcdedit command is used here to export the BCD store as a file: bcdbackup. There's no need to specify a file extension.

The command should return the following on screen:

```
    The operation completed successfully.
```

Meaning the BCD export worked as expected.

6. At this point, you need to adjust several file attributes for the BCD store so you can manipulate it.

At the prompt, execute the attrib command exactly like this:

```
    attrib c:\boot\bcd -h -r -s
```

This removes the hidden, read-only, and system attributes from the bcd file. Those attributes will restrict the actions you can take on the file. Now that they're gone, you can rename it.

7. To rename the BCD store, execute the ren command as shown:

   ```
   ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
   ```

Now that the BCD store is renamed, you should now be able to successfully rebuild it, as you tried to do in Step 2.

> **Note:** You could delete the BCD file entirely since you're about to
>   create a new one. However, renaming the existing BCD accomplishes the
>   same thing since it's now unavailable to Windows, plus provides you
>   yet another layer of backup, in addition to the export you did in Step
>   5, if you decide to undo your actions.

8. Try rebuilding the BCD again by executing the following, followed by the `Enter` key:

   ```
   bootrec /rebuildbcd
   ```

which should produce this in the Command Prompt window:

```
Scanning all disks for Windows installations.
Please wait, since this may take a while...
Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations: 1
[1]  D:\Windows
Add installation to boot list? Yes<Y>/No<N>/All<A>:
```

meaning that the BCD store rebuild is progressing as expected.

9. At the `Add installation to boot list?` question, type `Y` or `Yes`, followed by the `Enter` key.

You should see:

```
The operation completed successfully.
```

meaning that the BCD rebuild is complete.

10. Restart your computer.

> **Important:** Depending on how you started System Recovery Options, you may need to remove a disc or flash drive before restarting.

Comment: Thanks , i tried that one too and i still get "Total identified Windows installations: 0" on step 8

Comment: Ok, maybe try some of the other suggestions in that forum thread.

Comment: the situation doesn't look very good , does it? :)

Comment: Rather than waste anymore time on it, you may be better off just copying the data you need and reinstalling.